# Is it common practice to pay USED vacation at the end of the year?

Tags: salary, united-states, vacation, california

My friend has just learned that their California employer pays out **used** vacation at the end of the year. Even though the time off for vacation was taken in January, they will not receive money on their paycheck until December. The employee is non-exempt and paid hourly.

Is this a common practice? Are there any good references online that discuss this sort of policy?

Neither of us, nor anyone I've asked, has ever heard of an employer doing such a thing. I've searched everything I can think of, but I've been unable to find any mention of it.

Please note this isn't paying out *accrued* vacation (which *is* common), it's vacation time that has been used by the employee.

Comment: When vacation time is initially taken, is their paycheck reduced? What happens when someone leaves the company?

Comment: @DavidK Yes, their paycheck does not have the vacation hour paid. They will not receive payment for that vacation taken until December. I assume (I _hope_) if the employee leaves, then the employer will pay the unpaid vacation immediately, just like any other accrued-but-unpaid vacation.

Comment: This sounds really sketchy at best, illegal at worst.

Comment: @MikeHarris I agree, when I heard of it, I was sure that California would have some provision against it, but I'm surprised I've been unable to find _any_ mention of _anyone_ doing this, and I've found no mention in the labor code about when taken vacation must be paid (unless the employment is terminated).

Comment: I would have your friend immediately call the California Labor Department.  They can tell you the legality of this, but in 40 years in the workplace, I have never heard of a company doing this, so it may well be illegal.

Comment: Incidentally, whether it is legal or not, this is a company that would not retain me as an employee after the first time they tried this. Any company that would do this is likely to try to cheat their employees in many ways and is not one that anyone should be willing to work for unless they are starving to death.

Comment: Never heard of this before.  This does not sound normal at all.

Comment: doesn't appear to be illegal according to this, but IANAL: https://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/california-rules-vacation-paid-time-off.html

Comment: I can't think of an honest reason why a company would do this even if it is legal.  The only benefit I can see for them is that a percentage of people will forget they are owed pay that year, or lose track of how much they're owed, and the company can more easily defraud them.  If anyone can think of a legitimate reason to do this, I'd be interested to hear it.

Comment: Could the company be allowing vacation hours that actually haven't been accrued yet? If she's in the first year of work, she may not have any vacation hours until the end of the first year.

Comment: @mkennedy That is not the case, they have accrued more vacation time than they’ve taken.

Comment: I can see unused vacation time is paid out at the end of a year, in order to promote actually using the time over the entire course of a year, instead of allowing it to roll over into the next year or telling employees they will simply lose it.

Answer (score 10):

Common?  Hardly.

I've been in the workforce since the 80's and in many states (including CA) and this is literally the first time I've ever **heard** of that being done much less have it done to me.

If it were me, I'd be looking for new work because that just isn't normal and I'm not in the habit of loaning my employer a week's worth of pay for up to a year.

Comment: I would also be investigating whether this practice is legal. It's uncommon enough to make me wonder.

Comment: It's especially odd for California, which is a mandated payout state. It seems weird that they would be legally obligated to pay you for _accrued_ vacation but not for _used_ vacation.